# How to match user credentials against text file contents in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, text, command-line-arguments

I am trying to create a login method that checks user credentials against a text file called *"accounts.txt"* that has a strings such as *"Bob password"* already logged in it.

The `login` method parameters are like - "login" is the `command`, username (e.g. "Bob") is `param1` and password (e.g. "password*44") is `param2`.

When I run command line arguments, an example would be *"login Bob password"*
and the method should read contents of the file line by line until it finds a match and returns *"login Bob successful"*. Otherwise it'll say *"invaild username/password"*.

I'm not sure how to go about this, any tips are appreciated. This is my current code

```
protected void login(string command, string param1, string param2) // string command "login" string username, string password
{
     // login command
     // Needs to check accounts.txt file for username and password.
     // if username and password exists, provide logon message
     // if username and/ or password does not exist, provide failed logon message.
     // IN MEMORY store current login username and password

     //checks accounts.txt file if username already exists and if there is a match

     if (not sure what arg would go here)
     {
         string path = "C:\\Files\\accounts.txt";
         Console.WriteLine("username and password match", path);
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Login Failed: invaild username or password");
         string path2 = "C:\\Files\\audit.txt";
         using (StreamWriter sw2 = File.AppendText(path2))
         {
              sw2.WriteLine("Login Failed: Invaild username or password");
         }
         throw new FileNotFoundException();
 }
```

Comment: Are you seriously thinking that's a secure model? Anyone could just as easily read the password from the file. Consider using a SQL Server LocalDB for this, it's easier and far more secure.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath is right. You should at least add some security layer to your app to protect it from the mischievous users.

Comment: Just writing this code for practice to learn more and for fun, but I appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method would look like

```
protected void login(string command, string param1, string param2) // string command "login" string username, string password
{
    if (command == "login")
    {
        var logins = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Files\\accounts.txt");
        if (logins.Any(l => l == string.Format("{0} {1}", param1, param2)))
            Console.WriteLine("login {0} successful", param1);
        else
        {
            //log audit details
            Console.WriteLine("invaild username/password");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read all lines in one array and then try to find your string in this array.

```
string textToFind = string.Format ("{0} {1} {2}",command,param1,param2)
bool anyHit = File.ReadAllLines (path).Any(x => string.Compare (textToFind,x) == 0));
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `string.Compare` instead of `==`?

Answer (score 0):

As @Valentin already said you can read all lines of a text file with File.ReadAllLines().

```
string path = "C:\\Files\\accounts.txt";
string[] LoginCredentials = File.ReadAllLines(path);
for(i=0;i<LoginCredentials.Length;i++)
{
    //Split Line (Credential[0] = Username, Credential[1] = Password)
    string[] Credential = LoginCredentials[i].Split(' ');

    //Check if input matches
    if(param1 == Credential[0] && param2 == Credential[1])
    {
       Console.WriteLine("username and password match", path); 
    }
}
   // If Input never matched login failed
    Console.WriteLine("Login Failed: invaild username or password");
    string path2 = "C:\\Files\\audit.txt";
    using (StreamWriter sw2 = File.AppendText(path2))
    {
    sw2.WriteLine("Login Failed: Invaild username or password");
    }
    throw new FileNotFoundException();
```

Comment: This will **always** write *"Login Failed: invaild username or password"*. And you can make other improvement in the code as well.